# Python Click module treats options as arguments and errors out

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

What am I doing wrong here? My Click script has no arguments but has multiple options. My script is as follows:

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--error-percent-threshold")
@click.option("--latency-threshold")
@click.option("--node-type")
@click.option("--master-ip", default="0.0.0.0")
def main(node_type, error_percent_threshold, latency_threshold, master_ip):
    """Something"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now when I run my script with `python3 script.py --node-type=master --latency-threshold=50 --error-percent-threshold=1` I get the following error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --node-type=master --latency-threshold=50 --error-percent-threshold=1
```

Why is Click confusing my options as arguments?

Comment: Assuming the edits I made to your code are correct, I am unable to duplicate this error.  What versions of python and click are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8.10 and click 8.1.3

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate the error with python 3.9.12 and click 8.1.2. maybe try running some tests with `click.isolated_filesystem()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it wasn't Click after all. It was what I was doing in the script. I was trying to spin up Locust UI programatically. The args got parsed correctly but they were being passed to locust for some reason and locust was the one error out with the unrecognized args error. I was able to get around this with a `sys.argv = [sys.argv[0]]` right before I start working with locust in the script.